# create new column by adding 2 columns values as row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below column and data

```
id, FN,LN,address 
1,p,k,bangalore
2,M,K,Chennai
```

Output should be like  below

```
ID,NAME,Names,ADdress
1, FN,P,Bangalore
1,LN,K,Bangalore
2,FN,M,Chennai
2,LN,K,Chennai
```

can any one help me how to get above output in SQL-MYSQL

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. One select for FN, and one for LN.

Comment: @jarlh, hi thank you for ur information 
but my output should create new column and under newly created column two columns (FN,LN) and corresponding values should come 
if i use Union all new column wont create

Answer (score 0):

Do a `UNION ALL`, with one `SELECT` for the fn rows, and one `SELECT` for the ln rows:

```
select id, 'FN' as name, fn as names, address from tablename
UNION ALL
select id, 'LN' as name, ln as names, address from tablename

order by id, name   -- if required
```

Optional `ORDER BY`, keep it or remove it depending on the expected order.